# Why do I have to use the Application class to use WPF windows?

Tags: c#, wpf

I create my Window class

```
class myWin : Window
{
    public myWin()
    {
        Title = "My";
        MaxWidth = 500;
        MaxHeight = 500;
    } 
}
```

**Why I can not run 'myWin' without run Application's instance?**

Runs, but with **freeze**(Do not work).

```
myWin a = new myWin();
a.Show();
```

Works Perfectly!

```
myWin a = new myWin();
a.Show();

Application b = new Application();
b.Run();
```

I am using *Xamarin Studio*

Comment: Have you read the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597010%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: That's just how it works. You need an application start point, like static void main in a console app. Is it causing you a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the `Application` class implements all the necessary plumbing/infrastructure to run a Windows application.

The main part is the management of the **message pump** which processes all the messages sent by the OS to the application, particularly the repaint events which trigger the ... repaint of the rendering surface of the application.

So what the `Application.Run` do is essentially starting the **message pump**.